# How the following code is working in c++

Tags: c++, ns2

`Scheduler::Scheduler() : clock_(SCHED_START), halted_(0){ }`

How the above  is valid in `c++`, which was available in `scheduler.cc` of `NS2`  So any one  kindly explain about the above code. Thanks in advance

Comment: This basic stuff is covered in all C++ text books.- why not read one

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is this weird colon-member (" : ") syntax in the constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

Answer (score 1):

as @EdHeal said, check a C++ book

That's how you initialize members of a class while constructing an Object in C++. It can be used also for RAII technique.

When Scheduler is constructed, `clock` member is set to assume the value of SCHED_START and `halted` is set to assume value 0.